# Python package can't see global variable in another file

Tags: python

I'm having a lot of fun with a Python packing I'm creating. However I have a problem;

A variable that is suppose to be global can't be seen! This is the files

```
__init__.py
main.py
helpers.py
```

In main.py I have the following

```
from .helpers import *
class scene:
    def __init__(self,variables):
        self.variables = variables

global _scene
_scene = scene(100)
```

So I'm making a _scene that should be globally accessible. However this does not work in helpers.py;

```
from .main import *
print(_scene)
```

When i run I get the error :
NameError: name '_scene' is not defined

I think **init**.py is fine

```
from .main import *
from .helpers import *
```

What am I missing? Would love your input!

Comment: global affects only the file it is used in. also the issue seems to be due to a circular import, basically You import from `helpers` and that runs the module, meaning it will run the print before anything is defined

Comment: Thank you @Matiiss! How would you solve the issue? Not sure what the best practice is

Comment: `global` has no use in the global scope, it's only for use in method to tell you to use the global one

Comment: `from X import *` has a default behavior of omitting names starting with an underscore.  This can be overridden by putting an `__all__` list in the imported module, containing the names for `*` to include.  Or simply import the wanted name specifically.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea if you want to use global variables from a file and use them in other files and vice versa. It creates cyclical dependency. If you need to use a global variable in both files, you can define a third file `MyGlobals.py` and declare the global variables there. Then import that file into both `helpers.py` and `main.py` and access through `MyGlobals._scene`

Comment: MyGlobals would depend on main.py because the class is being created there, isn't that cyclical dependic as well?  

I'm getting some errors with modules not found with your solution. How would you import the MyGlobals?